# Python __getattribute__ and wrapper of method

Tags: python, wrapper, getattribute

I want to call a wrapper method of function with argument just **before** I call specific method.
So I guess I have to ovewrite `__getattribute__` method.

Here is an example of code:

```
def wrapper(func):
    return func * 2

class A(object):
    def test(self, arg):
        return arg + 1

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ['test']:
            return wrapper(super(A, self).__getattribute__(name))
        return super(A, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

The matter is that getattribute is called when `test` return the value. What I want is to be able to catch `test` with the arguments and define the wrapper method like this:

```
def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    print "do some stuff"
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Did you mean to place your parentheses as follows `return wrapper(super(A, self).__getattribute__)(name)`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: no, that'd not actually retrieve the method object. Take a look at my answer, where I separate out the `super()` call and the wrapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a factory function to return your wrapper:

```
def decorate(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        return f(*args, **kw) * 2
    return wrapper
```

Here `f` is closed over by `wrapper()`, so it can access the name when called.

Then return this in the `__getattribute__` hook:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    result = super(A, self).__getattribute__(name)
    if name in ('test',):
        return decorate(result)
    return result
```

Of course, you could also just apply `decorate` as a decorator on `test` then:

```
class A(object):
    @decorate
    def test(self, arg):
        return arg + 1
```

Comment: Ty for help. I can not change or affect `wrapper` (from another class). But I guess my only choice is to make a decorator on `test` method and I don't need to use `__getattribute__.`

Comment: @Katsu: yes, that'd be the better option. I assumed that wasn't an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a decorator.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) * 2

    return _wrapper

class A(object):
    @wrapper
    def test(self, arg):
        return arg + 1
```

Comment: +1: Yes it was I suggested previous comment Thank you